# Locus equation in a non-simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H \triangleleft G$, $H \ne \lbrace e \rbrace$. For given $h \in H$ and $g \in G$, let's set $R_g(h):=C_G(h)g \cap O_h$, where $C_G(h)$ is the centralizer of $h$ in $G$, and $O_h$ is the orbit through $h$ by conjugacy. We get:

$$\begin{align}
R_g(h) \ne \emptyset &\Leftrightarrow \exists y \in C_G(h), \exists x \in G \mid yg=x^{-1}hx \\
& \Leftrightarrow \exists z,x \in G \mid (zg=x^{-1}hx) \wedge (zh=hz) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists z,x \in G \mid (hzg=hx^{-1}hx) \wedge (zh=hz)\\
 &\Leftrightarrow\exists z,x \in G \mid (zhg=hx^{-1}hx) \wedge (zh=hz)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (z=hx^{-1}hxg^{-1}h^{-1}, x \in G) \wedge (zh=hz).
\end{align}$$

Now, $x \in C_G(h) \Rightarrow z= h^2g^{-1}h^{-1}$; but $h^2g^{-1}h^{-1} \in C_G(h) \Leftrightarrow g \in C_G(h)$, so that:

- $g \in C_G(h) \Rightarrow R_g(h)=\lbrace h\rbrace \cup \lbrace zg=hx^{-1}hxg^{-1}h^{-1}g \mid (x \in G \setminus C_G(h)) \wedge (zh=hz) \rbrace$
- $g \in G \setminus C_G(h) \Rightarrow R_g(h)=\lbrace zg=hx^{-1}hxg^{-1}h^{-1}g \mid (x \in G \setminus C_G(h)) \wedge (zh=hz) \rbrace$

**Special case**: $G$ abelian. Then, $C_G(h)=G$, $O_h=\lbrace h \rbrace$, $R_g(h)=\lbrace h \rbrace$.

Can $\lbrace zg=hx^{-1}hxg^{-1}h^{-1}g \mid (x \in G \setminus C_G(h)) \wedge (zh=hz) \rbrace$ be simplified somehow?

Comment: in your chain of implications, the fourth one, the forward implication is clear, but I'm not convinced that the reverse holds

Comment: Also, I think you forgot your definition of $R_g(h)$. You have $R_g(h)\subseteq O_h$ and in the abelian case $O_h=\{h\}$ so you must have $R_g(h)=\{h\}$. Are you perhaps looking for $C_G(h)\cap O_hg^{-1}$?

Comment: About your first comment: from that point on I removed the wedge but I could (should indeed) have kept it till the end. About your second one: could that mean that for $G$ abelian the only *nonempty* $R_g(h)$ is  $R_e(h)$ ?

Comment: keeping the wedge fixes the problem. No, for $G$ abelian you have $R_g(h)=\{h\}$ for all $g,h$, but $z\in C_G(h)\cap O_hg^{-1}$. You define $z$ by $zg\in R_g(h)$.

Comment: I think I got your point. I've edited accordingly.