# Locus equation in a non-simple group_part#2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

*(This is more a focused post than [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143956/locus-equation-in-a-non-simple-group) similar one of mine, and the question more direct.)*

Let $G$ be a group and $H \triangleleft G$, $H \ne \lbrace e \rbrace$. For given $h \in H$ and $g \in G$, let's set $R_g(h):=C_G(h)g \cap O_h$, where $C_G(h)$ is the centralizer of $h$ in $G$, and $O_h$ is the orbit through $h$ by conjugacy. Then: 
\begin{align}
R_g(h) &= \lbrace x^{-1}hx \in C_G(h)g \mid x \in G \rbrace \\
&= \lbrace x^{-1}hx \in C_G(h)g \mid x \in C_G(h) \rbrace \cup \lbrace x^{-1}hx \in C_G(h)g \mid x \in G \setminus C_G(h) \rbrace \\
&= \lbrace h \in C_G(h)g \rbrace \cup \lbrace x^{-1}hx \in C_G(h)g \mid x \in G \setminus C_G(h) \rbrace  
\end{align}

Now, $h \in C_G(h)g \Leftrightarrow g \in C_G(h)$; so, by defining $$\tilde R_g(h):=\lbrace x^{-1}hx \in C_G(h)g \mid x \in G \setminus C_G(h) \rbrace,$$ we get:

- $g \in C_G(h) \Rightarrow R_g(h)=\lbrace h\rbrace \cup \tilde R_g(h)$
- $g \in G \setminus C_G(h) \Rightarrow R_g(h)=\tilde R_g(h)$

---

Is there any class of $G$s such that:

- $g \in C_G(h) \Rightarrow \tilde R_g(h) = \emptyset$
- $g \in G \setminus C_G(h) \Rightarrow |\tilde R_g(h)|=1$ ?

(Given $h$, all the [right] cosets of the centralizer of $h$ would cross the orbit by $h$ one time, and only one.)

Comment: a "trivial" class of groups would be abelian groups. I think this is the 6th post in a series of questions? Is there some motivation for this line of inquiry? You may find more interest or additional information if you add motivation.

Comment: Robert, you're right. Here's the motivation behind that: I was looking for $G$s (if any) fitting in the "Earth-like model" shown here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136710/visualization-of-groups-with-a-normal-subgroup/3139241#3139241). A key feature would be to identify the cosets $C_G(h)g$ with the meridian segments and the orbits with circles in the equatorial plane ($H$). I argue this model as such may be failing, but I'd be glad to know that -with possibly some "structural amendment"- it can actually "show" at least some "special" $G$s.

Comment: Just had a flick through some of your posts. I'm quite enjoying the attempts to visualise groups. I would like to encourage you to keep thinking / posting about this. As well as being fun, trying to make these work / working out where they fail clearly leads to some nice questions!

Comment: I appreciate your valuable support, I'll keep going on. The beautiful Corollary in your answer is definitive in characterizing the $(G,H)$s I was looking for, though it invalids my Earth-like model as featured: no chance to have the equatorial cut ($H$) into any axial segment ($Z(G)$)... But this is part of the fun.

Comment: In the same hyphothesis, I'm wondering whether such a "relabelling" of (supposed) "meridian segments" does hold: $\forall h \in H, \exists h' \in H, \exists g' \in G \setminus C_G(h) \mid C_G(h')=C_G(h)g'$. I think its prove/disprove (in particular the latter) should give hints on how to amend the model.

Comment: So as you have written it, it won't be interesting as you could take $h'=h$, $g'=1$. Perhaps you want something like $\forall h\in H$, $\forall g\in G$, $\exists h'\in H$ such that $C_G(h')\cap O_h=1$?

Comment: Well, I assumed $g' \in G \setminus C_G(h)$, so it can't be the unit.

Comment: My mistake, then the property can't hold as $C_G(h')g'$ is a subgroup if and only if $g'\in C_G(h')$, so you would have $C_G(h)g'=C_G(h')(g')^2=C_G(h')g'=C_G(h)$ so $g'\in C_G(h)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can be rephrased as

> For which $G$ is $|R_g(h)|=1$ for all $g,h\in G$?

or more generally

> For which pairs $(H,G)$ with $H\trianglelefteq G$ is $|R_g(h)|=1$ for all $g\in G$, $h\in H$?

This can be answered completely as follows:

> Lemma: If $h\notin Z(G)$ then $|R_g(h)|\ne 1$ for some $g\in G$.

Proof: We show this by contrapositive.

Suppose $|R_g(h)|= 1$ for all $g\in G$.

From this we show that $G=C_G(h)O_h$. Indeed for $x,y\in C_G(h)$ and $z\in O_h$ there is some $x'\in C_G(h)$ with $xy=x'z$ if and only if $x^{-1}x'y=z$ which holds if and only if $z\in O_h\cap C_G(h)y=R_y(h)$. But $y\in R_y(h)$ and $|R_y(h)|=1$ so this holds if and only if $z=y$. Hence $xy=x'z$ for some $x'\in C_G(h)$ if and only if $y=z$ and therefore $x=x'$. Hence $|C_G(h)O_h|=|C_G(h)||O_h|=|G|$ by orbit-stabiliser, so $G=C_G(h)O_h$.

Now consider the natural quotient map $\varphi:G\to G/C_G(h)$. We have $\varphi(O_h)=\varphi(G)=G/C_G(h)$. But $O_h=\{h^x|x\in G\}$ and for $x\in G$ we have $\varphi(h^x)=\varphi(h)^{\varphi(x)}=1$ so $\varphi(O_h)=1$. Hence $G/C_g(h)=1$ and $h\in Z(G)$.

> Corollary: Let $H\trianglelefteq G$. Then $|R_g(h)|=1$ for all $g\in G$, $h\in H$ if and only if $H\le Z(G)$.